# How to mock HttpSession in JSF

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, junit, mocking, mockito

i have a service method that get session attribute and i want to make unit test for this service method and i was wondering how to mock the HttpSession in jsf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1- use the FacesContextMocker class:**

```
public abstract class FacesContextMocker extends FacesContext {

    private FacesContextMocker() {}

    private static final Release RELEASE = new Release();

    private static class Release implements Answer<Void> {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            setCurrentInstance(null);
            return null;
        }   
    }

    public static FacesContext mockFacesContext() {
        FacesContext context = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
        setCurrentInstance(context);
        Mockito.doAnswer(RELEASE).when(context).release();
        return context;
   }
}
```

**2- in the test class @Before method do the following:**

```
    FacesContextMocker.mockFacesContext();

    ExternalContext externalContext = Mockito.mock(ExternalContext.class);
    Mockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext())
            .thenReturn(externalContext);

    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Mockito.when(
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getRequest()).thenReturn(request);

    HttpSession httpSession = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);
    Mockito.when(GeneralUtils.getHttpSession()).thenReturn(httpSession);
```

**3- the getHttpSession method is as follows:**

```
   public static HttpSession getHttpSession() {

    return ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession();
}
```

**4- in the test method do the following:**

```
Mockito.when(
                GeneralUtils.getHttpSession().getAttribute(
                        "userID")).thenReturn("1");
```

**5- this is assuming that in your service method that you are making the unit test for you have code like:**

```
String currentUserID = (String) GeneralUtils.getHttpSession()
                    .getAttribute(userID);
```